# Differentiating and integrating simple functions like $f(x)=\log(\sin(x))\log(\cos(x))$ and $f'(x)=\cot(x)\log(\cos(x))-\tan(x)\log(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It's a simple, elementary thing to differentiate $f(x)=\log(\sin(x))\log(\cos(x))$ by the well-known formulae one learns in high school, and *Mathematica 9* perfectly does it. However, when integrating $f'(x)$, one might have the big surprise to find *Mathematica 9* gives a long answer in terms of logarithms and polylogarithms with complex argument.

*Question*: Could we force *Mathematica 9* to give us the simple primitive, which is in this case $f(x) + C$? If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: fyi, I tried this in Maple, and it also does the same as Mathematica. It seems FriCAS is only smart CAS so far to use FTOC on this. Screen shot attached ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L9R1d.png)  what seem to happens is that M evaluate $f'(x)$ and then tries to integrate the result. It does not check that integrand is already a derivative of some function. This is based on evaluation order.

Comment: Please write the equations in Mathematica syntax. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site). Once read the edit window help button `?` gives quick reminders of that material. To remove from the screen, click `?` again.

Comment: @Nasser thanks for info.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I have *Mathematica* installed on a different machine. For me it is fine how it looks like.

Comment: I have to correct something in my comment above., From a friCAS expert, I was told that FriCAS actually did not use FTOC on this. It actually differentiated the integrand as Mathematica did, but it also was able to integrate the result back to the original function! Fricas has advanced implementation of  Risch algorithm and so was able to do this.  I do not think it is possible to use FTOC here in any CAS I know, since the integrand will always get evaluated first, before Integrate gets chance to look at it. So it is impossible to do, due to evaluation order. This is how Maple works also.

Comment: @Nasser essentially there are tons of integrals like this one where one might meet the same issue. I wonder it this issue could be fixed in the next *Mathematica* version. For my research an upgraded version would be extremely useful.

Comment: `I wonder it this issue could be fixed` I doubt this very much. As I said, it is evaluation order. This is build-in the core of Mathematica. May be the second line in Mathematica original `main()` function in version 0.00001 :) You can't change this and WRI will not change it. Using `Hold` or such on the integrand will not work. Since once you remove these, we are back to square one.  You need something like lazy evaluator. But this is not how Mathematica evaluator works. And I do not how or even if it possible, to modify  `Integrate` at the user level to give it new rule to handle this case.

Comment: @Nasser oh, that's sad and depressing ... Thanks for the explanations.